# Change dateformat

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this code where I wish to change the dataformat. But I only manage to change one line and not the whole dataset.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ("data_q_3.csv")
result = df.groupby ("Country/Region").max().sort_values(by='Confirmed', ascending=False)[:10]
pd.set_option('display.max_column', None)
print ("Covid 19 top 10 countries based on confirmed case:")
print(result)
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromisoformat("2020-03-18T12:13:09").strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
```

Does anyone know how to fit the code so that the datetime changes in the whole dataset?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no format. `datetime` is a binary value, it has no format. Formats apply only when parsing strings into datetime values, or formatting datetime values into strings for display. You haven't posted any code that attempts to format a date field or display it. From this code it's not clear if there are any datetime fields at all. Perhaps it's `Confirmed`? Or another field?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your problem for a while, I figured out how to change the values in the 'DateTime' column. The only problem that may arise is if the 'Country/Region' column has duplicate location names.

Editing the time is simple, as all you have to do is make use of pythons slicing. You can slice a string by typing

```
string = 'abcdefghijklnmopqrstuvwxyz'
print(string[0:5])
```

which will result in abcdef.

Below is the finished code.

```
import pandas as pd

# read unknown data
df = pd.read_csv("data_q_3.csv")

# List of unknown data
result = df.groupby("Country/Region").max().sort_values(by='Confirmed', ascending=False)[:10]
pd.set_option('display.max_column', None)

# you need a for loop to go through the whole column
for row in result.index:
    # get the current stored time
    time = result.at[row, 'DateTime']

    # reformat the time string by slicing the
    # string from index 0 to 10, and from index 12 to 16
    # and putting a dash in the middle
    time = time[0:10] + "-" + time[12:16]
    
    # store the new time in the result
    result.at[row, 'DateTime'] = time

#print result
print ("Covid 19 top 10 countries based on confirmed case:")
print(result)
```